# 'Nonprobabilistic Sampling' versus 'Nonprobability Sampling'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, spanish, statistics

I'm writing a research paper, and I need to translate it to English. I hired a translator and I'm not sure that the following sentence has the right structure:

> Interventions: It was performed nonprobability sampling using the technique of simple random selection.

I think that the right way would be:

> A nonprobabilistic sampling was performed using...

1) Should it be nonprobabilistic or nonprobablity ... sampling?
2) What is the right order of words?

The original text in Spanish is:

> Se realizó muestreo no probabilístico mediante la técnica de selección aleatoria simple.

Comment: Your translation is correct. The translator is wrong.

Comment: I think there is a much more serious problem in this translation than grammar. How can "non-probabilistic sampling" be performed by "random selection"?  It seems to me that this is an oxymoron. If it's random, doesn't this mean that there's probability involved? Having googled both "non-probabiistic sampling" and "muestreo no probabilístico", it seems to me they don't mean the same thing ***at all***.

Comment: Nonprobability sampling: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonprobability_sampling What a perfectly *horrible* term! Couldn't they just say deterministic or some such?

Answer (score 1):

1. The phrase,"It was performed nonprobability sampling . . " is not good English. No native speaker would ever use this structure. One correct structure would be "Nonprobability sampling was performed.."
2. "Non-probability sampling" seems to be the preferred term. If you Google "nonprobabilistic sampling," most of the entries use the term "non-probability sampling."
3. Pete's point that random selection and non-probability sampling are opposites is well taken. Fiorella, you are the best person to determine whether "el muestreo no probabilístico" means the same thing as "non-probability sampling." There is a helpful brief article on non-probability sampling techniques at:
   http://www.statcan.gc.ca/edu/power-pouvoir/ch13/nonprob/5214898-eng.htm 
   Please let us know what you find.